# SQLite schema based on SQL Server DB schema

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlite, sqlite-net, dacpac

I maintain a Windows based application backed by SQL Server DB so there is a set of SQL entities, like tables, views. With time I add new features and fix bugs so schema of the tables and views changes. Once I need to deploy a new version of the application I deploy the DB part by relying on DacPac/[DacFx](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx) which automatically generates a difference between already deployed DB and the supplied DacPac so the already deployed DB is altered to match the DacPac's content. This way I don't have to write a code which compares 2 schemas and then generates a difference - DacFx does that for me.

That works well but now I need to expand the application so it also supports SQLite DB, I will for sure have to create a new application layer working with SQLite which is doable but one place I need help with is being able to create and maintain SQLite DB schema in the same way I do for SQL Server with DacPac/DacFx so a difference in schemas is computed and applied. While doing that I ideally want do write the SQL schema once so it could be applied to SQL Server as well as SQLite. Ideally, I need to generate SQLite schema based on the schema specific to SQL Server.

I looked into [sqldiff](https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html) which is capable of generating difference between 2 SQLIte DBs and thought I could:

- use a technique from [here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox) to migrate SQL Server schema to SQLite
- generate a temporary SQLite DB based on the generated above schema
- compare the above deployed temporary DB to an existing SQLite DB by using the *sqldiff* and finally apply the difference to the target SQLite DB

but the *sqldiff*, as stated in the **Limitations** section:

> The sqldiff utility is not designed to support schema migrations

In addition it has limitations around views:

> The sqldiff.exe utility does not (currently) display differences in
> TRIGGERs or VIEWs.

So I interpret that like that tool could probably be used for some migration cases but it is not really recommended.

How do you suggest generating and applying the schema differences?

I'm also interested to know how others solve the task of incrementally updating schema of their SQLite DB even if I take SQL Server completely out of equation and would instead maintain SQLite schema, in the source code, only. Does everyone create their own schema comparing tools instead of using something similar like DacFx in SQL Server world?